# How to use this Function on a custom API

Tags: c++

I have encountered a problem using an API which function is to send Mail but the problem is that the body of the mail is using LPCVOID to which i have no idea how to use it. I have search google and there is no clear explanation on how to use it.

Here is the whole function:

```
IMTMail::Body(LPCVOID body,const UINT body_size)
```

Parameters:

```
body       [in] A pointer to the email body
body_size  [in] The size of the body in bytes
```

I hope you can enlighten me and if you have examples i will really appreciate it.

Comment: LPCVOID is typedef of const void* i.e. it can point to any type of pointer. Just pass any pointer to the function and use it inside it.  typedef const void* LPCVOID;

Comment: yes i have tried it using LPCWSTR as a test. `m_mail->Body(L"This is a test",50);` but the result is a wild character then i use wstring `wstring body = L"This is a test mail."; m_mail->Body((LPCVOID)body[0],sizeof(body));` and the result is "This is a test m". I think sizeof(body) is not appropriate, need to increase size in order to read all.

Comment: @batch1999 `sizeof(body)` returns size of `std::wstring` class (the structural size of the `std::wstring` class) and not size of `body` object. You should use `body.size()`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments [`LPCVOID` is typedef of `const void *`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn363584.aspx). So you can pass any pointer to the function. And here are examples:

```
std::string body("Test Email Body!!!!!!!");
mail.Body( body.c_str(), body.size() ); //assume type of mail is IMTMail
```

with `std::wstring`

```
std::wstring body(L"Test Email Body!!!!!!!");
mail.Body( body.c_str(), body.size() ); //assume type of mail is IMTMail
```

Comment: i have tried your example but it returned an error. `Error C3867 'std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>::c_str': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`

Comment: @batch can you provide your code? Seems you forgot `()`.

Comment: i just fixed it. I just go with a simple html tags without using css on it because i think if you put too much characters on it as what would be the case if you use css. Now it works with the bland html output.

Comment: @batch1999 great. you can accept my answer if you think it is correct :)